# Return all rows of a dataframe where a value is in either of two specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, filter

I am new to Python trying to return all rows of a data frame where the team 'Liverpool' is listed in either the HomeTeam or AwayTeam columns. I can print a boolean result with this code for one column but I need the whole filtered dataframe to be returned with the filter applied simultaneously on both columns.

```
for i in df['HomeTeam'] == 'Liverpool':
    print (i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this if you meant they are in either one of the columns

```
df_new = df[(df['HomeTeam'] == 'Liverpool') | (df['HomeTeam'] == 'Liverpool')]
```

and this otherwise (i.e. both)

```
df_new = df[(df['HomeTeam'] == 'Liverpool') & (df['HomeTeam'] == 'Liverpool')]
```